# How to unmap ctrl+shift+r in kitty?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, kitty

The kitty terminal emulator uses the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for window resizing. The shortcut is also used by bash for reversing the reverse-i-search direction.

First I tried to to remove the kitty shortcut by mapping it to **no_op** using

```
map ctrl+shift+r no_op
```

But then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> inserts `4;6u` instead of the shortcut being passed to the shell like it does in other terminals.

As second option I tried mapping the shortcut to **discard_event** using

```
map ctrl+shift+r discard_event
```

But then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> behaves like no key was pressed at all.

Testcase:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Enter a term that appears multiple times in your bash history
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> again to get to the next match
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to get to the previous match (this step fails in kitty)

Answer (score 2):

The actual way to unmap a shortcut is to set the key map to `no_op`. For example:

```
map ctrl+shift+r no_op
```

`discard_event` stops the event from propagating period, so the running program never receives it.

Answer (score -1):

To unmap the keyboard shortcut defined by Kitty, try instead :

`map ctrl+shift+r discard_event`

Comment: The key is still not passed (correctly) to the shell. Testcase: press `ctrl-r` to reverse-i-search for a word. press `ctrl-r` again to get to the next match. Then press `ctrl-shift-r` to get to the previous one. With `no_op` you get `4;6u` inserted into the terminal and with `discard_event` nothing happens at all.

Comment: Yep, this doesn't seem to forward the keypress to the terminal, it just actually discards it, which makes it useless